# passing data in request using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a scenario where I want to pass the data from a dict to a endpoint in a for loop.

here is what I have tried :

```
data3= [{'spcg': [{'a_id': 234, 'b_id': 1122, 'cls': [{'address': '{"fgt":"Cc","Ik":"01","IV_Y":"CP1","IID":"0054","IY":1,"SL":"https://ap.com","OC":""}', 'cl_id': 456103, 'type': 'SC', 'name': 'SFTPC', 'srt': 'sdp%', 'oner': 'ar'}], 'adata': False}], 'e_id': 1122}, {'spcg': [{'a_id': 456, 'b_id': 1111, 'cls': [{'address': '{"fgt":"Cc","Ik":"01","IV_Y":"CP1","IID":"0054","IY":1,"SL":"https://ap.com","OC":""}', 'cl_id': 4545673, 'type': 'SG', 'name': 'SMC', 'srt': 'sdfe', 'oner': 'agtr'}], 'adata': False}], 'e_id': 1111}]
for key in data3:
    temp=(key['spcg'])
    ab=requests.post('https://app/v1/end', headers =headers_active_spc, data=temp)
    print(temp)
```

Error I am receiveing :

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

in

```
ab=requests.post('https://app/v1/end', headers =headers_active_spc, data=temp)
```

How can I pass all the `spcg` values ad body in POST request one by one as I tried in for loop.

Comment: Try data=json.dumps(payload)
or json=temp (that'll take care of it)

Comment: @Sharad json=temp ?

Comment: Make it `ab=requests.post('https://app/v1/end', headers =headers_active_spc, json=temp)` instead

Comment: @Saharsh Doesnt works , same error

Comment: @John are you sure? I just tried it and it seems to be working fine for me. (Only errors are related to HTTP Connection since that URL is invalid my system). `ValueError` will only appear when you are trying to pass a `dict` into `data` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try sending post request with JSON format `data=json.dumps(temp)`

where json can be imported as `import json`